# Factoring $(x^2+y^2-4)^2=(x^2+y^2-4x)(x^2+y^2-4y)+16$ "by hand"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How would you factor this by hand (ie, without a computer)?
>   $$(x^2+y^2-4)^2=(x^2+y^2-4x)(x^2+y^2-4y)+16$$

It should factor into the product of a line and a circle.

Comment: What do you mean by "factor by hand"? I mean, it's already factored...

Comment: I mean not using computers.

Answer (score 2):

First, move all the terms to the left hand side:$$(x^2+y^2-4)^2-(x^2+y^2-4x)(x^2+y^2-4y)-16=0$$
You notice that you have many $x^2+y^2$ combinations, so let's expand the multiplications in terms of this expressions:
$$(x^2+y^2)^2-8(x^2+y^2)+16-(x^2+y^2)^2+4x(x^2+y^2)+4y(x^2+y^2)-16xy-16=0$$
After cancelling the some terms, you get:
$$4(x+y)(x^2+y^2)-8(x^2+y^2)-16xy=0$$
We sum the last two terms together, since this looks like $(x+y)^2$
$$4(x+y)(x^2+y^2)-8(x^2+y^2+2xy)=0$$

$$4(x+y)(x^2+y^2)-8(x+y)^2=0$$
Now we factor $x+y$ out
$$4(x+y)(x^2+y^2-2x-2y)=0$$
The last term in parentheses can be transformed into a circle by completing the squares:
$$4(x+y)[(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2-2]=0$$
$x+y=0$ is the equation of a line going through the origin, with slope $-1$. The other part is the equation of the circle centered on $(1,1)$ with radius $\sqrt 2$.